# Show Woocommerce Grouped product up-sell products on its Simple product children

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to grab/show all up-sell products from the Woocommerce Grouped products to that products children.

I figured that it should be an if statement in the content-single-product.php under the upsell display but I couldn't take it from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards
Marcus

Comment: Could you post some code to show what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Hi @orciny. I haven't really gotten anywhere. I only know to use the <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_upsell_display' ); ?> but not more than that.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really the place for this then. You should really provide specific code problems. This question is a bit vague.